# Regex: find all classes in jquery that dont have prefix

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm trying to find all the css classes in a Jquery file that arent prefixed with p- yet.

This got me all the classes that are referenced first but still misses some from the snippet below. Can anyone help improve this?

`\('\.(?!p-)`

Here is an extract from the source I'm searching through:

```
animateSubElements: function(num) {
    var newNum = (typeof(num) == 'number' ? num : 1);
    TweenMax.to($('.p-section.current .col-right'), 0.3, {alpha: 0});
    TweenMax.to($('.p-section.current .col-right:nth-child(' + newNum + ')'), 0.3, {alpha: 1, delay: 0.3});
},
```

Here is a place to test suggestions: http://regexr.com/39da9

Answer (score 1):

Try this expression:

```
\('[^\)]*\.\K((?!p-)[a-z0-9\-\.]+)
```

http://regex101.com/r/fA2eK4/1

**Explanation:**

`[^\)]*` - match any characters with the exception of `)` as we search only text between `(` and `)`

`(?!p-)` - no prefix `p-`

`\K` - as match return text starting from this mark

`[a-z0-9\-\.]+` - match for class name only (include characters which is valid in names)

[Sublime Text search](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace_overview.html) uses the [Boost syntax](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html) for regular expressions.

Comment: could you please try to give more detail to what you've changed and why? it will for sure help the author of the question to improve in regexes. thanks

Comment: @BogdanEmilMariesan Try improved expression. Also added explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
\('\.(?![.]?p-)
```

This should do it.

Comment: @user909410 What's your expected output for the above input?

Comment: I'd like to have only the class names found that have no p- prefix. I'm using Sublime Text's search to search through my documents.