# Regex to find all jsp class attributes through Eclipse that contain a class that does not start with ((c|l|u|nav|js)-|dijit|dojo|dgrid)

Tags: java, regex

I'm finishing up a CSS refactor of a somewhat large Java project using Struts 2 and Dojo. I'm currently trying to find old CSS classes that might be leftover, pretty much the final stage of the refactor.

I'm trying to find a regex to find all jsp class attributes that contain a class that does not start with `((c|l|u|nav|js)-|dijit|dojo|dgrid)`. This will find all our own CSS classes, which are prefixed by those letter combinations plus a dash, as well as most of the CSS classes defined by Dojo that we may be using manually. I'm looking for something I can enter in the Eclipse find dialog.

the best I've found so far was `(?<=class=)"(\w|\s)*\b(?!(c|l|u|nav|js)-|dijit|dojo|dgrid)(\w|\s)*\b(\w|\s)*"`, but it doesn't actually exclude the dijit, dojo or dgrid classes and it doesn't work for class attributes with more than 1 class defined, AFAIK at least. I've also tried to adapt the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/25545691/1770430, but I can't get it to work properly.

Some strings to test on:

Match the first class here:

```
<td class="oldCssClassInFront c-table-basic__value-cell">
```

match the second class here:

```
<td class="c-table-basic__value-cell oldCssClassBehind">
```

Match nothing here:

```
<td class="c-table-basic__value-cell">
```

match first and last classes here:

```
<td class="oldCssClassInFront c-table-basic__value-cell oldCssClassBehind">
```

match this empty class too if possible, not required:

```
<td class="">
```

match the middle class here:

```
<td class="c-table-basic__value-cell oldCssClassBehind js-use-me">
```

match first class here:

```
<td class="oldCssClassInFront c-table-basic__value-cell dijitInline">
```

Comment: Try `(?<=class=)"\W*(?!(?:[clu]|nav|js)-|dijit|dojo|dgrid)\w+`. I added `\w+` at the end but I'm not sure if it matches what you want. Please add some sample inputs and show expected matches.

Comment: @revo Will that also match classes that are not defined as the first class in the attribute? This finds a number of them, but they all seem to be the first class in the class attribute.

Comment: Please provide us with some sample input strings and expected matches.

Comment: @revo I've added some example strings to clarify what I'm looking for in valid Regexes.